# Unity C# discord SDK how to get use guilds

Tags: discord, sdk

I am struggling with something that I thought would be basic. I am using Unity Discord SDK.
I am able to get user information... from there I can not get the guilds "server" that user belongs too.. no where I can find the property guilds.. see what I have:
[image]

Comment: What happens when you console log `user`

Comment: Can't test right now, but made progress on this by ditching this route, and actually ditching the Discord SDK for Unity.. what appears to be better is to do a bunch of POST/GET request with unity web request functionalities ... and Call discord API... of course it is easier said than done because  for this to work there is some setting on the Discord server side...